# In Azure Data Factory, my SecureString parameter is printed out in plain text in debug monitoring logs

Tags: security, parameters, azure-data-factory

I have a `Web Activity` with secure input/output set to `true`.

I have an `Execute Pipeline Activity` that references a pipeline with a `secureString` parameter.

I provide this `@activity('get_token').output.value` as the `secureString` parameter value inside the `Execute Pipeline Activity`.

In the logs, I can see the token printed out in plain text. Is this a feature, or a bug?

[image: Execute Pipeline Activity]
[image: Output is secure from Web Activity]
[image: Token is visible in debugging logs]

Answer (score 0):

> In Azure Data Factory, my SecureString parameter is printed out in plain text in debug monitoring logs

***Getting Input Output securely is not available for all activities like lookup and execute pipeline Activity.***

And when you enable this option for web activity or set variable It will only hide the output in monitoring logs.

it will pass the output to next activity with its type only so if you have set variable with string type and you enabled the secure output it will hide the output in monitoring log but pass Forword as string type only.

You can check [this](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/issues/637) feature request and give feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c)